# If the degree of five vertices in a simple connected graph of six vertices are $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ then what is the degree of the 6th vertex?

Tags: graph-theory

At first it is tempting to say $6$ but any idea if $6$ is actually the correct number and how to show it?

Comment: How can any vertex in a simple graph with $6$ vertices have degree $6$?

Comment: oh, you are right, wouldn't be simple, I am guessing it's 5 then?

Comment: What have you tried? Did you start drawing such a graph to see what restrictions are placed?

Comment: @CalvinLin yes I did, so if you could just help more or give an answer I would appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the vertices be $v_k$ of degree $k$ for $k=1,2,3,4,5$ and one more vertex, $v$. Since $\deg(v_5)=5$, there must be edges between $v_5$ and each of $v,v_1,v_2,v_3$, and $v_4$. Make a sketch and draw those edges. Now circle or otherwise mark $v_5$ to indicate that it has all of its edges, and do the same for $v_1$: it’s only supposed to have one edge, and it already has it, going to $v_5$.

Now look at $v_4$: it’s supposed to have $4$ edges, and it cannot have one to $v_1$, so it must have edges to $v,v_2,v_3$, and $v_5$. It already has that last one, but you can draw in the other three and mark $v_4$ as having all of its allotted edges. One other vertex can now be marked; which one? Can you finish it from there?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The vertex of degree 5 is connected to all the other 5 vertices.

**Hint:** The vertex of degree 1 is only connected to the vertex of degree 5.

Can you continue this approach?

Comment: I thought about this but didn't reach anywhere

Comment: @ayrebelcoding What can you say about the vertex of degree 4? Which vertices could it be connected to?